# Inserting text in table format using lua Hammerspoon

Tags: lua, lua-table, hammerspoon

I'm trying to create a script using lua in hammpersppon. Where pressing "x" will give the user option to paste the kind of template that they want to paste into a text field in web.

Unfortunately, I am not able to figure out how to format that text as tables ( with rows and columns)?

I tried pasting the table from google sheet (excel) into lua code but still, it doesn't render it as a table in the text field.

```
-- Focus the last used window.

local function focusLastFocused()
    local wf = hs.window.filter
    local lastFocused = wf.defaultCurrentSpace:getWindows(wf.sortByFocusedLast)
    if #lastFocused > 0 then lastFocused[1]:focus() end
end



-- On selection, copy the text and type it into the focused application.

local chooser = hs.chooser.new(function(choice)
    if not choice then focusLastFocused(); return end
    hs.pasteboard.setContents(choice["subText"])
        focusLastFocused()
    hs.eventtap.keyStrokes(hs.pasteboard.getContents())
end)



chooser:choices({
      {
         ["text"] = "Option 1",
         ["subText"] = [[ Text 1 Text 2

                          Text 3 Text 4]]

      },
      {
         ["text"] = "Option 2",
         ["subText"] = [[ Text 1 Text 2

                          Text 3 Text 4]]

      },

})
hs.hotkey.bind({"X"}, "X", function() chooser:show() end)
```

Answer (score 0):

Insert Newlines as `\n` and horizontal tabs as `\t`.
See also [link](https://www.lua.org/pil/2.4.html).

```lua
> print('1\t2\n3\t4')
1       2
3       4
```

Comment: Okay. Did you try to use the [hs.styledtext](https://www.hammerspoon.org/docs/hs.styledtext.html) object? You can also use this in `choices.subText` instead of a string value. It allows you to style the text.

Comment: hs.styledtext doesn't have any options for this :(

Comment: Tried sth. like this `subText = hs.styledtext.new('Text 1\tText 2\nText 3\tText 4')`? There wouldn't be an option to configure the tabstops, if you aren't able to do some.

Comment: @moh17 did you try it?

Comment: I tried something like this, but it does not appear like a tale :(